# Did chat just die?

Tags: support, chat, downtime, outage

I can't seem to load anything on https://chat.stackexchange.com (main page, transcripts, user pages, rooms).

I also checked on https://isup.me and it said it was down too.

Anyone else getting this, and is there an explanation for where chat went?

Specifically, the connection keeps timing out (Firefox, Google Chrome) and it just suddenly died out of nowhere; I was just chatting and a message failed to send so I reloaded and the page just wouldn't connect.

Comment: I noticed the same. Just posted an article about Mexico in the Arqade news chatroom and it died.

Comment: Down for me too - the various mains and metas seem to be fine though

Comment: Clearly this is a sign that I need to stop talking in chat so much.

Comment: Seems, so. All chat servers (Chat.SO, Chat.SE, and Chat.Meta.SE) died unexpectedly.

Comment: oddly enough, neither Catija nor Nzall's comments triggered a "x new comments" - maybe sockets are dead for whatever reason?

Comment: Yep, I got no notifications that this question was edited and/or that there were new comments. I just refreshed and they were there.

Comment: Websocket also died.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, chat uses websockets.

Comment: Can confirm, new comments aren't showing the message and I have to reload manually. Looks like websockets are just gone, and chat entirely went too \*shrug\*

Comment: It's back on, I guess.

Comment: We're digging into what went wrong. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I was just able to post a message to chat.MSE.

Comment: Websockets still appear to be dead.

Comment: @Catija happy digging! Hope you won't bump into ancient bones. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 Oh... well... I'm not doing the digging. :P I get to flop around like everyone else waiting for the news from the experts to understand what happened.

Comment: Websockets look to be restored now, sometime in the last 10 minutes or so

Comment: @zcoop98 Chat is dead; long live chat!

Comment: Maybe still seeing socket intermittent failures? I thought for a bit it was just me, but it's been on and off for long enough now that I'm not so sure.

Comment: @Catija any finding so far? Or is this one of the "Temporary glitch that can't be explained in any way" cases? (Which is fair, no service can have 100% uptime.)